# How to reduce the font size of placeholder in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, placeholder, searchbar

I have a UI where the placeholder text fits the search bar. This is the UI which I need.

[image]

This is my UI

[image]

This is my custom renderer code

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(searchTab), typeof(StyledSearchBarRenderer))]
namespace RestaurantApp.Droid.Renderers
{
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
    class StyledSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var color = global::Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightGray;

                var searchView = Control as SearchView;

                int searchPlateId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
                Android.Views.View searchPlateView = searchView.FindViewById(searchPlateId);
                searchPlateView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

                int searchIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
                ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.FindViewById<ImageView>(searchIconId);
                searchViewIcon.SetImageDrawable(null);

            }
        }
    }
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
}
```

This is my XAML code

```
 <Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" OutlineColor="DarkGray" HasShadow="True" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <local:searchTab x:Name="searchBar"  Placeholder="Please search for a vendor or product name" PlaceholderColor="Black" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />

            </Frame>
```

I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this `EditText textView = (searchView.FindViewById( textViewId ) as EditText);
textView.SetTextSize(12);`

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you pull down the text size it manages the placeholder as well

Comment: @user3452 - Can I write as answer, If you don't mind.

Comment: Yeah sure @CGPA6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change `HintText` of `SearchView` we need to find `EditText` of `SearchView`.

```
var textView = (searchView.FindViewById(textViewId) as EditText);
```

Now after getting instance of `SearchView`'s `EditText` we can set `textView` we can set all types of properties like `SetBackgroundColor`, `SetHintTextColor`, to name a few.

So your code to change `HintText` (Placeholder) would look like this

```
var textView = (searchView.FindViewById(textViewId) as EditText);
textView.SetTextSize(12);
```

Note: When we are changing the `TextSize` Hint Size as well getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to understand is that your users' screen size will vary depending on the device they use. Setting the font size to an absolute is exponentially overcomplicating it.

[Apple's HIG for the SearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/search-bars/) keeps its guidelines short and simple, and should help you with the UI that will benefit your app (even if it targets Android only). In your example, you would like to display the text `Please search for a product vendor or name`. This is by every UI guideline out there an **instruction**. The searchbar placeholder needs to be a **hint**, for example *Search*, *Product*, *Vendor*, *Product or Vendor name* (the list goes on).

The text you have should appear as a label above the search bar, so that the user knows that is the instruction they must follow. Then in the search bar, you'd show a short placeholder for your search bar (examples above). In fact, you can improve the UI by having the instruction in a label, but have an example search string as your place holder (example: *Apple iPhone*) so that the user has an example of what to write.

Alternatively, you can remove the "please type in ..." and just have the search bar placeholder as *Product/Vendor name*. The user will still know to search for by product or vendor name.

Doing the above will avoid having to create unnecessary complex custom renderers.